# Set value in gridview for dropdownlist template. Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, templates, gridview

I have problem with DropDownList template in Grid View, after I go in edit mode drop down have to be selected by current item instead of default value.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tour Type">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataSourceID="dropDownListSqlDataSource" runat="server" DataValueField="idTypetour" DataTextField="title"></asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%#Eval("typeTitle")%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I tried to use SelectedValue="<%#Eval("typeTitle")%>", but has no results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `Bind` instead of `Eval`:

```
SelectedValue='<%# Bind("idTypetour") %>'
```

The DataValueField is "idTypetour" and the DataTextField is "title", you have tried to use Eval("typeTitle"). What column is `typeTitle`? I assume that this must be `idTypetour` because you want to set the SelectedValue, what normally is the ID.

Here are informatons on the differences:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx